# Delete a row from gridview in back end c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to delete a gridview row in the back end. When I click `delete` it deletes from the `gridview`, however it does not delete from the database. Can anyone see why this may be? My code is as follows:

```
protected void GVMyBookings_DeleteBooking(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
     string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BookingConn"].ToString();
     SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(connstring);

     MyConnection.Open();

     SqlDataSource SDSBooking= new SqlDataSource();
     SDSBooking.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM Tbl_Booking WHERE BookingID_PK = @BookingID_PK";
     SDSBooking.DeleteParameters.Add("@BookingID_PK", GVMyBookings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].ToString());
     SDSBooking.ConnectionString = connstring;

     GVMyBookings.DataSource = SDSBooking;
     GVMyBookings.DataBind();
     MyConnection.Close();
}
```

The gridview is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVMyBookings" runat="server" GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
    OnRowDeleting="GVMyBookings_DeleteBooking" EmptyDataText="You have no upcoming bookings" >
    <RowStyle BackColor="#e5ecbf" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingID_PK"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingDate" HeaderText="Booking Date" 
            SortExpression="BookingDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RoomName" HeaderText="Room Name" 
            SortExpression="RoomName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="Start Time" 
            SortExpression="StartTime"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndTime" HeaderText="End Time" 
            SortExpression="EndTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StaffUID" HeaderText="StaffUID" 
            SortExpression="StaffUID" Visible="false" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#264409" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your query is incorrect

```
DELETE * FROM Tbl_Booking WHERE ID=@BookingID_PK
```

Use this instead

```
DELETE FROM Tbl_Booking WHERE ID=@BookingID_PK
```

Remove the `@` symbole from this line

```
SDSBooking.DeleteParameters.Add("BookingID_PK",...);
```

Then call Delete explicitly against the dataSource

```
... 
SDSStudents.ConnectionString = connstring;
SDSStudents.Delete();
GridView1.DataSource = SDSStudents;  
...
```

Comment: An error occured on the SDSBooking.Delete() saying:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to data type int

Comment: @Claire Try to replace this `GVMyBookings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].ToString()` by `GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text`

Comment: No error, it deletes from the gridview, but then when I refresh the page it is there again - so it still isn't updating the database. Is this all in the correct order?:
    SqlDataSource SDSBooking = new SqlDataSource();
    SDSBooking.ConnectionString = connstring;
    SDSBooking.Delete();
    SDSBooking.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM Tbl_Booking WHERE BookingID_PK = @BookingID_PK";
    SDSBooking.DeleteParameters.Add("BookingID_PK", GVMyBookings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
    GVMyBookings.DataSource = SDSBooking;
    GVMyBookings.DataBind();
    MyConnection.Close();

Comment: @Claire `SDSBooking.Delete();` and `SDSBooking.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM Tbl_Booking WHERE BookingID_PK = @BookingID_PK";` are reversed

Answer (score 0):

Your code sequence to delete the record from database should be like this.

```
//Declaring the datasource.
SqlDataSource SDSBooking= new SqlDataSource();

//Providing the delete command.
SDSBooking.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM Tbl_Booking WHERE BookingID_PK = @BookingID_PK";

//Adding the parameter for deleting the record.
SDSBooking.DeleteParameters.Add("BookingID_PK", GVMyBookings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);

//Providing the connection string.
SDSBooking.ConnectionString = connstring;

//Executing the delete method of the SqlDataSouce. 
//It is this line that will actually delete your record.
SDSBooking.Delete();
```

After this you can assign this datasource to you gridview.

**Note :** For `GVMyBookings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text`, you need to make sure, that your databound field is at index `1` in the TableCellCollection.

You might need to change, if you are generating some other columns before it.

As because in your case the delete button would be generated before your databound field. So the delete button would be at index 0 & your databound field *BookingID_PK* would be at index 1.